# I need an onkeydown function that limits the number of decimal places of that a html form can accept

Tags: javascript, html, decimal, onkeydown

For example, the html form should stop accepting decimal places after 0.1 so it wouldn't be possible to type in 0.01 to the html form box, thank for any help provided

Comment: @Spectric im not sure how to accept an answer, also could you rewrite the function to be caled from a keydown event

Comment: It currently is being called from a keydown event. That's why the first parameter in `addEventListener` is `"keydown"`.

Comment: @Spectirc could I please get your help answering another one of my questions that asks to combine your function with more code that also limits the number of alphabet character that can be typed in the, BTW thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: @Spectric https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503922/please-help-combining-one-function-that-limits-the-number-of-decimal-places-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match values where there is only 1 decimal place. If the test fails, use [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```js
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(!/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value + e.key)){
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: What about special keys, how do you delete? While this answer satisfies the original requirements, it needs a lot of effort to make it work.